# Java socket permission denied: connect

Tags: java, sockets, mongodb, networking, redis

I have trouble about network connection.

Here's the situation.

Java application(JSP or console) should connect to MongoDB and Redis.

In the fisrt environment,

- Java -> local  mongodb : OK
- Java -> remote mongodb : OK
- Java -> remote redis : OK

In the second environment which has trouble (more secure),

- Java -> local  mongodb : OK
- Java -> remote mongodb : Exception
- Java -> remote redis : Exception

Funny thing is that mongo.exe (console) connects to remote mongodb w/o problem.
(I havn't tested at redis)

I've upgraded latest version of java.
Converted JSP version to java console for test.
And changed some codes.
Nothing works.

```
m = new MongoDB( ADDRESS, PORT );
m.setReadPreference( ReadPreference.SECONDARY );
DB db = m.getDB("test");
db.authenticate( ID, PASS.toCharArray() ); //!< exception
```

MongoDB Exception Message

```
DBPortPool gotError
Warning: emptying DBPortPool to [ADDRESS...]:27017 b/c of error
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/[ADDRESS...]:27017]     bc:java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Redis Exception Message

```
JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

I think it involves some security issues.
Second PCs are in much strict security network.
(I use them via VPN)

Answer (score 1):

Self-answer.
This is an issue related to JDK7 and VPN.
http://www.java.net/node/703177

Comment: Could You please include essential parts of the post instead of just linking some offsite resource? Which is actually down long since.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to telnet on to the remote host and listening ports (provided the remote computer has not blocked telnet attempts altogether)?  I am assuming you are sure about the remote IP address/port number since you mentioned that your mongo console was able to connect from the first computer to the second one.  If you really needed to show to someone that this is a network issue, you could look at using wireshark etc on the both computers - you will be able to see the packets leaving the first computer but getting rejected from the second one.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. It's not about connecting first computer to second computer. First env is PC1->PC2, second evn is PC3->PC4. Anyway, as mongodb connection in console works, telnet works well. Only problem occurs in Java (of second evn). Thank you for replying.

Comment: yes - that's exactly what I mentioned (I was only talking about the second environment).  In the second environment, can you telnet from PC3 to PC4 & setup wireshark on both computers for network connectivity confirmation?  If its a Linux environment, does PC3 or PC4 have any firewall/IP tables setup that is blocking the connection?  Run netstat -an | grep 6379 to confirm whether redis is running on that port on PC4 or not.

Comment: I'll try wireshark soon. Thank you. And... PC4(linux) is set appropriate IP tables. Both MongoDB (console) and node.js from PC3 can connect to PC4. But, I'm not sure PC3's firewall is set appropriately. (Due to security policy, I cannot disable firewall or manipulate freely for testing) I'm wondering java should be given special authority or something for network.